# How to get facebook profile picture of user in facebook SDK 3.0 Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

i am using facebook SDK 3.0 i have to get profile picture of user login.
Here is the code I use:

```
URL image_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture" );
profPict=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(image_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

But I don't get the desired result.

Comment: i am also looking for same and not getting accurate profile picture used same code :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should change your code following:

```
URL image_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture" );
```

Possible GET parameters for the URL can be found here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/

Answer (score 16):

Use **https://** instead of **http://**  i faced the same problem.

```
URL image_value = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture" );
profPict = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(image_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

Comment: I have solved same problem with your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

If you are trying to display profile pic in your app, use `ProfilePictureView` from Facebook SDK.

[Refer This](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/ProfilePictureView/)

Just call `setProfileId(String profileId)` on it.

It will take care of displaying the image.

Comment: Is it solving the problem?

Comment: is it loaded async-lly?

Comment: Yes, it loads images async-ly :)

Comment: is there a way to use this with the app - scope id i get for the users friends?

Comment: @ZivKesten by scope id, do you mean profile id, if yes then you just have to call 'setProfileId()' method, with that profile id.

Comment: the scope id is what i get for my user's facebook friends in the new facebook sdk, it is uniq per user but it is not the actual facebook id, there is no way that i know of to get the facebook id for my friends in the new sdk

Comment: In the new sdk, setProfileId is not working it is not loading an image showing default avatar. If anyone has idea let me know

Answer (score 5):

Use `ProfilePictureView` from facebook sdk.

Comment: It is not loading an image using user-id very strange behavior

Answer (score 5):

```
String id = user.getId();
try {
  URL url = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+ id+ "/picture?type=large");
  String image_path = uri.toString();
  System.out.println("image::> " + image_path);
}
catch (MalformedURLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this inside a thread:

```
String url = "http://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture";
HttpConnection conn = new HttpConnection(url);
conn.openConnection();

Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream()), "image");

conn.close();
```

I hope it help you.

Answer (score 2):

try this..

```
 try {
        imageURL = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" +
                                                id+ "/picture?type=large");
        Log.e("URL", imageURL.toString());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
             try {
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageURL
                                .openConnection().getInputStream());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }

      ProfileDp.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Once your facebook account is logged into the application, simply do:

```
String url = Profile.getCurrentProfile().getProfilePictureUri(x, y).toString();
```

x and y are width and height.

See the doc : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/Profile/