# Facebook sdk 4.0.1 can't get some fields with Android studio

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am working on a login function with facebook for my android app.

I have almost everything done but i can't get all the fields.

Im getting only something in fullname and the fbid.

First name, Gender, Profile picture returns nothing.

```
  GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject fbUser,
                                                GraphResponse response) {

                            final ParseUser parseUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
                            try{
                                parseUser.fetchIfNeeded();
                            }catch (Exception e){}

                            if (fbUser != null && parseUser != null
                                    && fbUser.optString("name").length() > 0) {
                                Log.d("fb","Json--"+fbUser);
                                parseUser.put(USER_OBJECT_NAME_FIELD, fbUser.optString("first_name"));
                                   parseUser.put("fullname",fbUser.optString("name"));
                            try{
                                   String mm= fbUser.getString("email");
                                    parseUser.setEmail(mm);
                                }catch (Exception e){//e.printStackTrace();
                                  }
                                   try{
                                    String mm= fbUser.getString("gender");
                                    if(mm.equals("male"))
                                    {
```

For profile pic i'm using this:

```
          try {
                                    final String id = fbUser.getString("id");
                                    parseUser.put("fbId", id);

                                    //Your code goes here
                                    String ur = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?width=640&height=640";
                                    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
                                    imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
                                    imageLoader.loadImage(ur, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap bmImg) {
                                            // Do whatever you want with Bitmap
                                            if(bmImg!=null) {
                                                bmImg=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmImg,640,640,false);
                                                ParseFile dL = new ParseFile("dpLarge.jpg", bmImg.toString().getBytes());
                                                Bitmap smal = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmImg, 120, 120, false);
                                                ParseFile ds = new ParseFile("dpSmall.jpg", smal.toString().getBytes());
                                                parseUser.put("dpLarge", dL);
                                                parseUser.put("dpSmall", ds);
                                            }
```

**Permissions:**

```
      facebookLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loadingStart(false); // Facebook login pop-up already has a           spinner
            if (config.isFacebookLoginNeedPublishPermissions()) {
                  ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithPublishPermissionsInBackground(getActivity(),
                        config.getFacebookLoginPermissions(), facebookLoginCallbackV4);
            } else {
                ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(getActivity(),
                        config.getFacebookLoginPermissions(), facebookLoginCallbackV4);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Can't figure out what im doing wrong.

Comment: What permissions you are requesting?

Comment: I have  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> and  <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" /> in the AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: Sorry, im not talking about the manifest permission, but facebook permissions,
Please check this answer -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/32776987/1879661 and make sure your are calling the right permissions like `"public_profile", "user_friends", "email", "user_birthday"`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't already used facebook sdk, but according to your problem with a profile picture, did you tried solutions from these posts:

[How to get facebook profile picture of user in facebook SDK 3.0 Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372593/how-to-get-facebook-profile-picture-of-user-in-facebook-sdk-3-0-android)

[How to get facebook profile picture of user in facebook SDK Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907742/how-to-get-facebook-profile-picture-of-user-in-facebook-sdk-android)

Try also to use some logs for example to check if `String ur` appears correctly.

Comment: Really strange. If you have an facebook account, please join this group (https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/) and there paste this issue